# How to stop chart from printing in this cell but the next cell with really short code

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

These codes produce a chart

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))
```

Jupyter notebook automatically print the chart, even I didn't call `plt.show()`. I don't want to show the chart in the same cell with the code but the next cell by running a really short code such as `plt.show()`. In order to keep the cell as concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose all your plot-related statements inside a function called plot_and_show().  Then you can call the function when you are ready.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

def plot_and_show():
    p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
    p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
                 bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

    plt.ylabel('Scores')
    plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
    plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
    plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

plot_and_show()
```